# How to resolve "top level statements must precede namespace and type declarations" error

Tags: c#, .net, .net-7.0

I am creating a basic console application in C# 7.0 (I am very new to C#) and I am creating a game class to allow for a multi-file project, but it is spitting out an error:

> Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations.

The class itself is not getting any errors but the code after the class **is**.

Here is an example to illustrate my point:

```
public class game 
{
    Console.WriteLine();
}

int u = 0;
```

Bear in mind that I do not know how namespaces work in C# and all the examples I could find are in .NET 6.0 or lower.

Comment: Basic C# syntax has been the same since the beginning, and the code you have now has never been valid. Outdated examples isn't a valid excuse to not read them.

Comment: @GuyIncognito: Top-level statements make a very significant difference here. While the code *as written* isn't valid anywhere, similar code would not have been valid before C# 9 but now is.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
namespace you_namespace
{
public class game 
 {
    public void output(int u)
     {
     Console.WriteLine($"u = {u}");
     }
 }
}
```

Classes live in namespaces, so I created one to contain the game
class. Variable declarations and initialisations need to be inside a class or a method like output(). Just fooling around here, but it's the principle you have to grasp. I advice to take a beginners course in C#, to start off prepared.

Comment: "Classes live in namespaces" - they don't have to. The code you've written would compile just as well without the namespace declaration. Most class declarations *do* occur within namespace declarations - although I'd personally recommend using a file-scoped namespace declaration in most cases now.

Comment: And "Variable declarations and initialisations need to be inside a class or a method like output()" doesn't take into account top-level statements. See https://gist.github.com/jskeet/1d4fe3de1d7b3d044de2627672510ff0 for example.

Answer (score 1):

The error is fairly self explanatory:

> Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations.

Although the important part is ***... and type declarations.*** and you should move your class declaration to make sure it's after any other top-level statements:

```cs
int u = 0;

public class game 
{
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

This will at least clear the error you're currently getting but you're likely to get another one caused by `Console.WriteLine();`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually did'nt even know that classes could live outside of namespaces

Comment: They don't, they exist in the assembly's namespace (the project's name) just as if they had been declared in a separate file in the same folder.

Comment: @phuzi: Classes can *absolutely* exist outside a named namespace, and as far as I can tell, by default the `Program` class containing top-level statements is not part of any namespace by default. (Try printing out `typeof(Program).Namespace` in the code you've written...)

Comment: @JonSkeet I stand corrected. I was looking at the AssemblyQualifiedName - `game, <nameofproject>` - and missed that there was no prefixing namespace.